# How to mock arrays in EasyMock

Tags: java, arrays, easymock

I am trying to mock array of objects in `EasyMock` but am getting either null pointer exception OR not working at all.

getArgs() is an array of objects. Using below line, array of objects is mocked.

```
EasyMock.expect(invMock.getArgs()).andReturn(new Object[] {to});
```

In the below line, I am setting length of the array object but getting `null pointer exception.

```
EasyMock.expect(invMock.getArgs().length).andReturn(1);
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Dumb question: Did you call EasyMock.replay()?

Comment: @Christopher.. yes. EasyMock.replay() is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way it works.

You are expecting `invMock.getArgs()` to return an array of one element. This is done by your first line.

You don't need to record the length. Your array `new Object[] {to}` is an actual array of length one.

Comment: many thanks for the response.. Henri. EasyMock.expect(invMock.getArgs()).andReturn(new Object[] {to}).anytimes() resolved the issue.

Comment: Great. You can also use `EasyMock.expect(invMock.getArgs()).andStubReturn(new Object[] {to})` if you don't care about how many times it's called